# Rails Tutorial Unable to find field "Name" at spec run after 10.34

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I am going through the Rails tutorial and I have an issue that seems to be causing a lot of other tests to fail. There are 23 errors and most of them explain that there is a missing field called "Name". When I run the command

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb
```

I get the following errors (that seem to change order every time I run it):

> 1) User pages edit with valid information 
>        Failure/Error: fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
>        Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find field "Name"
>        # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:136:in `block (4 levels) in '

As a result, many other cases seem to fail. What app file would cause this issue? sessions_helper.rb?

---

Here is my spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb: require 'spec_helper'

```
describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "index" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before do
      sign_in user
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_title('All users') }
    it { should have_content('All users') }

    describe "pagination" do

      before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
      after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

      it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

      it "should list each user" do
        User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
          expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
        end
      end
    end

    describe "delete links" do

      it { should_not have_link('delete') }

      describe "as an admin user" do
        let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
        before do
          sign_in admin
          visit users_path
        end

        it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
        it "should be able to delete another user" do
          expect do
            click_link('delete', match: :first)
          end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
        end
        it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let!(:m1) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Foo") }
    let!(:m2) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Bar") }

    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }

    describe "microposts" do
      it { should have_content(m1.content) }
      it { should have_content(m2.content) }
      it { should have_content(user.microposts.count) }
    end
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "after submission" do
        before { click_button submit }
        signup_errors
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do

      before { valid_signup }

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_welcome_message( 'Welcome')}

        describe "followed by signout" do
          before { click_link "Sign out" }
          it { should have_link('Sign in') }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_content("Update your profile") }
      it { should have_title("Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_title(new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { expect(user.reload.name).to  eq new_name }
      specify { expect(user.reload.email).to eq new_email }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What does your HTML form look like? Is there a name field?

Comment: Voted to close, but I haven't read through to see whether it is a reasonably stated question or not. It is just too long to read.

Comment: Do you have "Name" field in your view?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's quick reply. I understand that it's a crappy vague question, I wasn't sure how else to ask. When I click on sign in both email & password fields are there. However when I click on sign up, there is no form there at all! I will go back through the code, but can anyone suggest if an error like this would cause the form to not show up or visa versa?

Comment: I don't think this is a crappy question.  Its hard when you're a beginner to know which code is important to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error you receive when running your spec suggests that `Capybara` expects a field called `"Name"` to fill (because you ask it to at line `fill_in "Name", with: new_name`).

If for some reason, after sign-in you don't get to the user form, or the user form is missing the `"Name"` field - that would explain your failures.

In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258573/rails-tutorial-unable-to-find-field-name-at-spec-run-after-10-34#comment33814099_22258573) you say that you get no form after sign-up, so that would definitely explain that.

To verify that, you can add a test to `describe "page"` like this:

```
it { should have_field("Name") }
```

If that fails - you can't expect any of the tests counting on that field to pass...